# How to convert a specific cell in an SQLite database into a string inside a WinForms textbox?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite, datagrid

Hi I am currently making a budgeting program for a school project and am having trouble with inputting a string converted from the SQLite table it is connected to externally. Here is my code:

'''

```
public entGlobalBUD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SQLiteConnection sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection();
            sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "DataSource = SubjectTable.db";

            //Deifine a SELECT statement
            string commandText = "SELECT * FROM SubjectTable";

            //Create the data table
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();

            //Create SQLiteDataAdapter
            SQLiteDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(commandText, sqlConnection);

            sqlConnection.Open();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(datatable);
            sqlConnection.Close();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
            budgetBox.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[23].Cells[5].Value.ToString();


        }
```

'''
The last line is the one causing the problem as if removed the program runs fine but leaves the Budget Box empty. With this last line in the code the program will not run. After debuggin the problem occurs because the 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index' my table is 24x6 and still fails even if something like [2], [2] is inputted.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

managed to solve it through a bit more research. Wasmy mistake needed to replace the last line of

```
budgetBox.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[23].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
```

to

```
budgetBox.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[23].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
```

Hopefullly this helps if anyone comes across something similar in the future.